# Why am I getting a nullPointerException when Clojure code calls a JPanel function?

Tags: java, swing, clojure, runtimeexception

I am having trouble determining why my code gets a nullPointer exception. I'm trying to write a swing application using a combination of Java and Clojure. I have a Clojure function that calls a function in my JPanel subclass, and I'm getting a lot of exceptions that are driving me crazy.

I've simplified my code as much as possible, and I'm still getting these errors.

```
(defn draw-state
  "Draws the current state."
  [state display]
  (do-swing (.drawBlocks display)))
```

Here's the entire JPanel subclass, although I think the only relevant part is the drawBlocks function (which eventually will be replacing the blocks array):

```
public class TDisplay extends JPanel {


private Block[] blocks = new Block[1]; 

/**
 * Create the panel.
 */
public TDisplay() {
    setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED, null, null, null, null));
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 5));
    blocks[0] = new Block(3, 4, 0);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    for (Block b : blocks) {
        if (b == null) continue;

        switch (b.colour) {
        case 0:
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            break;
        case 1:
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            break;
        }                               
        g.fillRect(b.x * Block.SIZE, b.y * Block.SIZE, Block.SIZE, Block.SIZE);
    }                
}

public void drawBlocks() {
    System.out.println("Hello world");
}
```

}

And the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:28)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeNoArgInstanceMember(Reflector.java:263)
at core$draw_state$fn__401.invoke(core.clj:43)
at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24)
... 8 more
```

I have the feeling that I'm missing something *really* obvious, and I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: How about the code that invokes `draw-state` -- is it possible that's passing in `null`s for `display`?  What is `state`?

Comment: *sigh* Display was getting passed in as null. Thanks for making me notice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the code that invokes draw-state -- is it possible that's passing in nulls for display?

Comment: Yes. There's two hours I'll never get back.